# Weird Wi-Fi adapters on Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, adapter

I have the following adapters on [`ipconfig /all`](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html):

```
Wireless LAN adapter חיבור מקומי* 7:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CENSORED :)
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter חיבור מקומי* 5:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CENSORED :)
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I don't think they are doing anything good around there. Is there a way to remove them?

I am on Windows 8.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable your [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) on Windows 8.1.

This is a tutorial:

*[Network Adapter (NIC) - Enable or Disable in Windows](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/37681-network-adapter-nic-enable-disable-windows.html)*

This is for removing the virtual network adapter:

*[Add or remove a virtual network adapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708372(v=ws.10).aspx)*

You could try this in a cmd prompt as administrator too:

```
 netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
 netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
```

Comment: The adapters aren't in the `Change adapter settings` panel and the address in the second tutorial doesn't work.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't work or the address.. The address is on.. It works for me

Comment: The part of opening administration website

Comment: That removed the `adapter 7` one, but `adapter 5` is still there.

Comment: Why you would remove LAN adapter 5??

Comment: I don't know what it does and it looks like its always disconnected, and it just makes finding stuff on `ipconfig/all` harder

Comment: Read it: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/what-is-microsoft-virtual-wifi-miniport-adapter/

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: It explain what is and why you shouldn't remove it